# Rails / Postgres: Get percentage of availability

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date

I am using a Postgres database (`CalendarEntry`) in which I store entries with `start_date` and `end_date` values.

Now I want to check if I am available for a certain timespan (`check_start`, `check_end`):

```
count_entries = CalendarEntry.where('start_date <= ?', check_end).where('end_date >= ?', check_start).count
i_am_available = count_entries == 0
```

I want to change this behavior to get the percentage of availability.
How could I count the available days instead of the entries themselves?

Comment: Why are you calling calender entrees Calender? Thats insanely confusing.

Comment: Is it possible that the timespans of some calendar entries overlap?

Comment: No, those are separate entries. I think I have to use the generate_series functionality somehow...

Comment: So you want to do it in the database? I think using ruby would be easier.